# (lectures) Reference request for Vector bundles and characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Are there some available online lectures for first year graduate course on vector bundles and characteristic classes?

Comment: I really like the book of Milnor and Stasheff, except the chapter on obstruction theory. Are you looking for something else? What do you want out of the notes?

Answer (score 1):

These notes by Randal-Williams seem pretty nice: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~or257/teaching/notes/Kthy.pdf

Another one is Hatcher's notes on vector bundles:

http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf